# How let the tables of camunda to another schema

Tags: spring-boot, camunda

I am using Camunda work flow engine with Spring Boot. 
But when I use the default config of the Camunda to start application.
The Camunda will create lot of tables on my business schema. 
The question is how let the camunda create itself tables to another schema.

I tried config the `camunda.bpm.database.schema-name`  to another schema name, But it doesnt work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

you could create a database user with any name for example "camunda" and then add this code in application.yml

```
 camunda.bpm:
    job-execution-enabled:  true
    history-level: full
    auto-deployment-enabled: true
    id-generator: strong
    checkProcessDefinitions: true
    deployment-resource-pattern:  classpath:/process/**/*.bpmn
    dataSource:
      schema-update: true
      schema-name: camunda
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.250.134:1521:TESTDB
      username: camunda
      password: camunda
```

then add this class

```
package org.vahidAlizadeh.service;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.IdGenerator;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.persistence.StrongUuidGenerator;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration;
import org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.ResourcePatternResolver;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
@Configuration
@Import( SpringProcessEngineServicesConfiguration.class )
public class CamundaConfiguration  {
    @Value("${spring.camunda.bpm.history-level}")
    private String historyLevel;


    @Autowired
    private ResourcePatternResolver resourceLoader;



   @Bean
  // @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.camunda.bpm")
   public SpringProcessEngineConfiguration processEngineConfiguration() throws 
   IOException {
    SpringProcessEngineConfiguration config = new SpringProcessEngineConfiguration();

    config.setDataSource(camundaDataSource());
    config.setDatabaseSchemaUpdate("true");

    config.setTransactionManager(transactionManager());
    config.setHistory(historyLevel);

    config.setJobExecutorActivate(false);
    config.setMetricsEnabled(false);
    config.setJdbcBatchProcessing(false);
    // deploy all processes from folder 'processes'classpath:/process/*.bpmn
    Resource[] resources = resourceLoader.getResources("classpath:/process/**/*.**");
    config.setDeploymentResources(resources);

    StrongUuidGenerator ss=new StrongUuidGenerator();
    config.setIdGenerator(ss );
    System.err.println("start resource address");
    for (Resource resource : resources) { 
        System.out.println(resource.getFilename());
    }
    return config;
  }

  @Bean                                                                
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(camundaDataSource());
  }
  @Bean(name="camundaBpmDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.camunda.bpm.dataSource")
    @Profile("dev")
    public DataSource camundaDataSource() {
        System.out.println("spring.camunda.bpm.dataSource");
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
   }
  @Bean(name = "camundaBpmDataSource")
    @Profile("prod")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() throws SQLException, NamingException {
        JndiTemplate jndi = new JndiTemplate();
        DataSource dataSource = (DataSource) jndi.lookup("camunda");
        return dataSource;
    }
  @Bean
  public ProcessEngineFactoryBean processEngine() throws IOException {
    ProcessEngineFactoryBean factoryBean = new ProcessEngineFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setProcessEngineConfiguration(processEngineConfiguration());
    return factoryBean;
  }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I already got the answer form the camunda forum.

Here is the answer of get from the camunda forum.

> if you want to use a different schema then you must create the
>   database tables by your own. It can only create the tables on the
>   default schema. Additionally, you must set the table prefix in the
>   configuration.

Here is [the solution link](https://forum.camunda.org/t/how-let-the-tables-of-camunda-itself-create-into-another-schema/8571)

Comment: @GiganticMistake Thank you remind me. I will add the essential parts on my answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

You could try changing the *databaseTablePrefix* property in the processes.xml configuration file.

Source: [Process Engine Configuration](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/reference/deployment-descriptors/tags/process-engine/)

Comment: Thank you. But it dose`t work. I guess this is a bug.