# How to separate Camunda tables to a different schema?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, datasource, camunda

I want to separate Camunda tables to a different schema called **camunda** but even if I gave the **schema-name** and **table-prefix**, it still put all the tables under the **public** schema.

[image]

Here's my application.yml;

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      pool-name: CAMUNDA-HIKARI-POOL
      idle-timeout: 3000
      maximum-pool-size: 10
      minimum-idle: 30
      username: ${X_DB_USER:xxxx}
      password: ${X_DB_PASSWORD:yyyy}
      connection-timeout: 2000
      connection-test-query: select 1
      transaction-isolation: TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${X_DB_URL:localhost:5433/x-table?autoReconnect=true}
  jpa:
    show-sql: false
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    open-in-view: false
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
camunda.bpm:
  admin-user:
    id: xxxx
    password: yyyy
  metrics:
    db-reporter-activate: false
  history-level: full
  database:
    schema-update: create-drop
    schema-name: camunda
    table-prefix: camunda.
```

What should I do more to let Camunda tables be under the **camunda** schema?

Comment: probably a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51889676/how-let-the-tables-of-camunda-to-another-schema

Comment: So there is no way to create another schema apart from **public** by camunda configurations of application.yml ? @yuppie-flu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example for two instance which are using separate database schemas (cam1 and cam2) and not the public schema:
https://github.com/rob2universe/two-camunda-instances

Comment: This is not working. I tried this application but still it pushes all the tables under public schema.

Comment: Trust me, I tested this before publishing it. I assume you have not configured the database users correctly. Have you created additional users or are you running everything with one admin user connecting to the default schema?

Comment: I just created user cam1 and I assigned all privileges from pgAdmin4 to that user and I added that user in application yml for postgres but still doesn't create the cam1 schema. What should I need to do more?

Comment: Typically an application's db user would not have all privileges. Try just creating a normal user cam1.

Comment: What do you mean by normal user? I just created another user and just gave login permission to it but still the same problem. Could you please add your user configuration from pgAdmin into your github page? That would be the solution.

Comment: Okay it is working now but I had to create the schema by myself. It was written that schemas will be created automatically.

Comment: Schema auto creation can also work. Please accept my answer